# AngularJS, $watch running twice, can't get old/new value comparison to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, watch

I'm using AngularJS and I want to watch if a variable changes, and the decrease another variable. Here's what I have:

```
$scope.$watch('watchMe', function () {
    $scope.decreaseMe--;
)
```

The watchMe variable is available to all scopes. I only have one controller which contains both a function where watchMe is changed as well as the watch.

Watch is running twice each time watchMe is changed and I understand that this is the way Angular works. However, that means that decreaseMe will be wrong, since it will be decreased twice as well.

I've tried comparing old and new values but I can't get it to work.

I'm outputting old/new/decreased values and this is what I get when watchMe is changed once:

```
old: 7  new: 8 
decreasing  5
old: 7  new: 8 
decreasing  4
```

What should I do to decrease decreaseMe only once when watchMe is changed?

---

Update:

### Tried to make a Plunkr to show this but in Plunkr $watch only fires once..

Comment: can you show us, how you did the compare between old and new value?

Comment: A fiddle or plunker would be very helpful here.

Comment: how is watchMe shared with all scopes? unless its rootscope i dont get it.

Comment: Will add fiddle/plunkr as soon as I can.

As for the shared data part, I have followed this example: https://github.com/mhevery/angular-node-socketio/tree/master/public

Comment: @Michael I did the comparison as suggested in the answer provided by acrmuui below. But I didn't get it to work (see my comment on that answer)

Comment: Didn't manage to make a Plunkr to show off this problem, see my update..

Answer (score 2):

Is this not working?

```
$scope.$watch('watchMe', function( newVal, oldVal ) {
    if( newVal != oldVal ) {
        $scope.decreaseMe--;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is what I meant to show with the output above. In the two iterations that are executed, newVal is 8 and oldVal is 7 in both iterations. That means that newVal != oldVal will be true both times and decreaseMe would be decreased twice.

Comment: wouldn't `newVal != oldVal` always evaluate to `true`?

Answer (score 0):

You should share a lot more code so we can see how you are set up. In any case, I've run into a similar problem before when I referenced the AngularJS lib twice on my page.

Comment: Will share fiddle/plunkr as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar issue when using directive templates with a shared controller. This means that your controller code gets run twice.

(Try outputting to the console in your controller but outside your watch statement to prove this, you should see a duplicate)

```
.directive('directiveOne', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'app/templates/directive-one.html',
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'directiveController'
    };
})
.directive('directiveTwo', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'app/templates/directive-two.html',
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'directiveController'
    };
})
```

The solution was to separate them out into their own controller

E.G.

```
.directive('directiveOne', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'app/templates/directive-one.html',
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'directiveOneController'
    };
})
.directive('directiveTwo', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'app/templates/directive-two.html',
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'directiveTwoController'
    };
})
```